# Cross compiling Erlang/OTP for Android 5.1, ssl crashes

Tags: android, linux, ssl, erlang

I want to cross compile Erlang/OTP for Android, so I downloaded the OTP source code with version 19.0.

I make the project as the doc said:

```
./otp_build boot -a
./otp_build configure --enable-dynamic-ssl-lib --with-ssl=/home/mengmeng/openssl --xcomp-conf=xcomp/erl-xcomp-arm-android.conf
./otp_build boot -a
./otp_build release -a /tmp/erlang
./Install -cross -minimal /tmp/release/erlang
```

When i push the OTP into an Android device, it can work, but when I check the ssl version it crashed without any info:

```
3> ssl:versions().
Segmentation fault
```

[image: crash screenshot]

Does Erlang/OTP not support Android 5.1 with ssl?